# Add timestamp to filename in curl command

Tags: curl, sh

I'm looking to add a time stamp or just the date to a file name once it has been downloaded from a remote server using a curl command. I know you can use -o to specify what you want to name the file. I have seen suggestions like: -o "somefile $(date +\"%H:%M\").txt"
to try to achieve this but I can't quite get it working, it just saves the file as  'somefile $(date' like it doesn't recognize $ as a variable.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this using curl or if it is possible?

Is there another way to create a variable with the date and then append it onto the file name?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't use single quotes? `-o 'some file $(date +"%H:%M").txt'` would produce the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 8):

It works perfectly fine with a variation of what you showed:

```
curl -o prefix-$(date +%H-%M) http://example.com/
```

Comment: Windows 11 powershell error `Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "+%H-%M" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:23`