# Curl command to output filename with a timestamp

Tags: curl, cmd

I want to take the json response from a url and save it to a .json file using curl from the windows command prompt.

My goal is to add a timestamp to the file name.

The following does not work.

```
curl -k --ntlm -u : --write-out '%{json}' https://myurl.com -o "myfile$(date +\"%H:%M\").json"
```

It results in a file like this with no content.
[image]

The following works fine and produces the expected output, but with no timestamp.

```
curl -k --ntlm -u : --write-out '%{json}' https://myurl.com -o "myfile.json"
```

How can I get a `.json` file with a timestamp?

I've tried both suggestions here and nothing seems to work.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37409968/7763687)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
curl -k --ntlm -u : --write-out '%{json}' https://myurl.com -o "myfile%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%.json"
```

`%TIME%` is a Windows built-in dynamic environment variable, and `~0,2` and `~3,2` take hours and minutes substrings from it.

Please note that colon is not allowed in file names in Windows, so I replaced it with a dash.

Comment: Worked beautifully!  Thank you so much @Renat

Comment: Please note however, that using `%TIME%` is dependent upon the end users specifc configuration, so `%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%` will only work for some end users, not all, and if spaces are not wanted, probably not for the majority.